# Decompressing gzipped data with Inflater in Java

Tags: java, gzip, zlib

I'm trying to decompress gzipped data with `Inflater`. According to the docs,

> If the parameter 'nowrap' is true then the ZLIB header and checksum
>   fields will not be used. This provides compatibility with the
>   compression format used by both GZIP and PKZIP.
>
> Note: When using the 'nowrap' option it is also necessary to provide
>   an extra "dummy" byte as input. This is required by the ZLIB native
>   library in order to support certain optimizations.

Passing `true` to the constructor, then attempting to decompress data results in `DataFormatException: invalid block type` being thrown. Following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9779941/783547), I've added a dummy byte to the end of `setInput()`'s parameter, to no avail.

Will I have to use `GZIPInputStream` instead? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java documentation is incorrect or at least misleading:

> nowrap - if true then support GZIP compatible compression

What nowrap means is that raw deflate data will be decompressed.  A gzip stream is raw deflate data wrapped with a gzip header and trailer.  To fully decode the gzip format with this class, you will need to process the gzip header as described in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952), use inflater to decompress the raw deflate data, compute the [crc32](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html) of the uncompressed data using that class, and then verify the crc and length (modulo 2^32) in the gzip trailer, again as specified in the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).

Comment: By the way, they also misspelled the name of the class.  It should have been "inflator".  Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

I think that to read a GZIP stream it's not enough to set `nowrap=true`, you must also consume  the gzip header, which is not part of the compressed stream. See eg. `readHeader()` [in this implementation](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream-source.html)