# How to improve GZIP performance

Tags: java, performance, gzip

Currently I do have the problem that this piece of code will be called >500k of times. The size of the compressed `byte[]` is less than 1KB. Every time the method is called all of the streams has to been created. So I am looking for a way to improve this code.

```
private byte[] unzip(byte[] data) throws IOException, DataFormatException {

    byte[] unzipData = new byte[4096];

    try (ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
         GZIPInputStream gzipIn = new GZIPInputStream(in);
         ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        int read = 0;
        while( (read = gzipIn.read(unzipData)) != -1) {
            out.write(unzipData, 0, read);
        }

        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

I already [tried](http://java-performance.com/) to replace `ByteArrayOutputStream` with a `ByteBuffer`, but at the time of creation I don't know how many bytes I need to allocate.

Also, I tried to use `Inflater` but I stumbled across the problem descriped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076060/decompressing-gzipped-data-with-inflater-in-java).

Any other idea what I could do to improve the perfomance of this code.

**UPDATE#1**

- Maybe [this](https://github.com/jasonk000/fastzlib) lib helps someone.
- Also there is an open [JDK-Bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142920).

Comment: Try increasing the `unzipData` buffer size. 4096 is not very big and I suspect increasing it will allow you to write more data with less write calls.

Comment: @GiantTree OP stated that `data` is less than 1KB, so increasing buffer size would be a waste,

Comment: @Andreas  I just skimmed the text; you are right, it won't help in terms of performance. He could pass the `new ByteArrayInputStream(data)` directly to the `new GZIPInputStream` without creating an intermediate InputStream.

Comment: @GiantTree That still creates the stream, just won't assign it to a variable, so won't do anything to performance.

Comment: @Andreas Yes I tried already some different buffer sizes, and 4k is the best tradeoff in my use case.

Answer (score 4):

1. Profile your application, to be sure that you're really spending optimizable time in this function. It doesn't matter how many times you call this function; if it doesn't account for a significant fraction of overall program execution time, then optimization is wasted.
2. Pre-size the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. The default buffer size is 32 bytes, and resizes require copying all existing bytes. If you know that your decoded arrays will be around 1k, use `new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048)`.
3. Rather than reading a byte at a time, read a block at a time, using a pre-allocated `byte[]`. Beware that you must use the return value from `read` as an input to `write`. Better, use something like Jakarta Commons [IOUtils.copy()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it applies in your case, but I've found incredible speed difference when comparing using the default buffer size of GZIPInputStream vs increasing to 65536.

example: using a 500M input file ->

```
new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toFile())) // takes 4 mins to process
```

vs

```
new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()), 65536) // takes 10s
```

J

More details can be found here http://java-performance.info/java-io-bufferedinputstream-and-java-util-zip-gzipinputstream/

> Both BufferedInputStream and GZIPInputStream have internal buffers.
>   Default size for the former one is 8192 bytes and for the latter one
>   is 512 bytes. Generally it worth increasing any of these sizes to at
>   least 65536.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Inflater` class method `reset()` to reuse the `Inflater` object without having to recreate it each time. You will have a little bit of added programming to do in order to decode the gzip header and perform the integrity check with the gzip trailer. You would then use `Inflater` with the `nowrap` option to decompress the raw deflated data after then gzip header and before the trailer.

Comment: Any existing code that has this readily available? I would like to use any such implementations than mess up the logic especially with CRC.